# Got UnboundLocalError error when implementing string mutation of genetic algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I am implementing genetic algorithm where data look like:

```
b=[['00000001', '00000010', '00000011'], ['00000011', '00000100', '00000101']]
```

Here each list in the list is individual. I need to define mutation:

```
def mutation(x, mutation_rate):
    for i in range(len(x)):       #### X is selected individuals. Say, from [[a,b,c], [c,d,e]], [a,b,c] selected
        p=[]
        if random() < mutation_rate:                           #### Make mutation based on certain probability#
            for bit in range(len(x[i])):   ### as each gene are 8 bit binary strings. So each append in list for operation
                m=x[i][bit]
                p.append(m)
            for c in p:               ### Apply operation on each 8 bit binary strings
                if random() < .01:
                    p[c] = '1' if p[c] == '0' else '1'
                    if c == 0:
                        b = p[c] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7]
                    elif c == 1:
                        b = p[0] + p[c] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7]
                    elif c == 2:
                        b = p[0] + p[1] + p[c] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7]
                    elif c == 3:
                        b = p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[c] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7]
                    elif c == 4:
                        b = p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[c] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7]
                    elif c == 5:
                        b = p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[c] + p[6] + p[7]
                    elif c == 6:
                        b = p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[c] + p[7]
                    else:
                        b = p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[c]

        x[i]= b                  #### put modifined gene to individual

    return x
```

But get error. It is saying:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment

Can anyone suggestion me what is the problem of this code. 
Thanks

Comment: if random() is never < .01, the variable `b` is never initialized. That's what the error message says.

Comment: if your condition is ( if random() < mutation_rate:) its false you try assing "b" value, but "b" is not created, you must be defined it previously

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception you should always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: So that we don't spend time retracing the steps you have already taken to figure out what is wrong, please tell us what you have ruled out as the problem and how you came to those conclusions.

Comment: for now just define `b` as an empty list like `b = []`, just before the `for-loop`.